# Resolving ip-address of a hostname

Tags: java

I have the DNS server IP address and a hostname.

Using Java, how can I find the IP address of the hostname as returned by that DNS server using the IP address and the hostname?

Comment: `dig <hostname>` in a command-line?

Comment: How to do the same in java code and where should I use DNS-Server ip address and hostname.

Comment: Another query will we need to provide the DNS Server ip address in any case or will it try to find it by default.I'm a bit confused here whether we need to use only the hostname or hostname+dns-server ip address too?

Comment: The lookup of the address using the name is not complicated. As long as you just use the system's default resolver. So: do you really need to use the DNS server address?

Comment: I have the same question : Do I reallly need DNS server address or will it resolve the address by default.BTW I am using a AIX Unix server.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Take a look at [`InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) and the [`getHostAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29) method.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.example.com"); 
System.out.println(address.getHostAddress());
```

Comment: Say if I have a dns ip address 10.37.221.152 and a host name say "www.student.com" then how can I find the ip address.

Comment: @DarkMatter: `InetAddress` should get the DNS resolved address when you ask for `getHostAddress()`. I'm not sure if you can force it to use a *specific* DNS server though.

Comment: So it has to ideally resolve by itself without the programmer specifying the DNS server address explicitly right?

Comment: @DarkMatter Yes. I believe it uses whatever DNS server is set on the computer itself.

Answer (score 34):

You can do it like this:

```
for(InetAddress addr : InetAddress.getAllByName("stackoverflow.com"))
    System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress());
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use InetAddress for this. Try the below code,

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.yahoo.com");
System.out.println(address.getHostAddress());
System.out.println(address.getHostName());
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by all above, you can use
`InetAddress.getByName("hostName")` but this can give you a cached IP, Read the java documentation for the same. 
If you want to get a IP from DNS you can use:

```
InetAddress[] ipAddress = DNSNameService.lookupAllHostAddr("hostName");
```

Comment: In addition to what @daksh pointed out, you can disable the DNS response cache as suggested [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0445.html) but be aware of the timing of disabling the cache as well as caching of DNS responses made by your OS as well as other DNS servers as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl). Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason this call gives me positive result for just any hostname. I thought I defaults to my IP, but no, it gives me some specific IP for any unknown host.