# The communication problems between android and server using hostname

Tags: android, windows, hostname

I'm using the socket service in my application

> mSocket = new SocketIO("ip:port"); //work smoothly

However we need to use the "hostname" instead of ip. When I refer to "hostname", it means the "hostname" command in windows.
The image below is the command I'm using.

[image]

When I use the hostname instead of ip

this way

> mSocket = new SocketIO("hostname:port"); //not work

android launches an android error -

io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking with hostname. Unable to resolve host "null": No address associated with hostname

Comment: mSocket = new SocketIO("hostname"); why dont you specify the port too as you do it above?

Comment: Is this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788605/3862022 working as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) server your device is configured to use does not have an entry for the name.  Thus the name can't be resolved to an address.  You need to configure your DNS correctly to be able to use names.