# Using agent name instead of IP as Address in SNMP4J

Tags: network-programming, snmp, snmp4j

I'm trying to make a program that sends SNMP queries to some switches in the network.

Using the Net-snmp tools, I can send get requests to the switch using its name, and it works fine. But SNMP4J requires an IP address in `CommunityTarget`, so I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```java
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
transport.listen();

CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress("switchName")); // exception happens here
comtarget.setRetries(2);
comtarget.setTimeout(1000);
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the IP address by using DNS resolution, like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788453/resolving-ip-address-of-a-hostname) says:

```java
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(switchName); 
System.out.println(address.getHostAddress());
```