# How to find ip address through hostname in local network?

Tags: android, linux, shell, unix, networking

I want to find `IP Address` of device through their `hostname` in local network. Lots of applications in market do this. It gives both `IP Address` and `hostname`, like `Fing` , `IP Tools` and many more. But still I am unable to find `IP Address` from `hostname`.

I am able to find `IP` of `hostname` by using `dig`, `arp` and `ping` command in `ubuntu OS 14.04` see following command:

`dig @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 example.local`

This command gives me output like this :

```
 ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 example.local
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56566
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.local.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.local.      10  IN  A   192.168.0.142

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.142#5353(224.0.0.251)
;; WHEN: Mon May 30 17:01:06 IST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

That specific `ANSWER SECTION` gives me `ip` against `hostname`.
also when I used following command :

`arp -vn example.local`

It gives me following output:

```
Entries: 4  Skipped: 4  Found: 0
example.local (192.168.0.142) -- no entry
```

Also when i ping device with their `hostname`

`ping example.local`

It also gives me `IP Address`:

```
PING example.local (192.168.0.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
```

But When I am doing above commands on `adb shell`, most of the command are not found. `arp` and `dig` is not present in android. 
And when I ping device through adb shell with their `hostname`, It gives me following error:

`ping: unknown host example.local`

But when I ping through `ip` of device, It successfully ping:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.142                                         
PING 192.168.0.142 (192.168.0.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=263 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=231 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.82 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.99 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=122 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.142: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=5.63 ms
```

Above things are done in same network, but still I am not getting `IP` through `hostname`(When I used same command from `adb shell`). How can I find `IP` through their `hostname` on `android` device using `adb shell`. 
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using wrong host name in ping command "example.local" while using adb shell. Your device does not know that hostname. You need to  tell your device that IP 192.168.0.142 belongs to Host: example.local. This can be achieved using DNS server configuration(pretty complex) or editing hosts file on device (root required on device)

Comment: I am newbie in android. How I can use DNS server configuration?

Comment: oh it is not related to android at all. you need to configure DNS server of your network which will say "example.local" has ip 192.168.0.142. But I am not sure why you need the ip address by hostname. If you can tell us  the use case, probably we can help out with alternate solutions

Comment: If you are developing an app, you can use android java api [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788453/resolving-ip-address-of-a-hostname)

Comment: @SangramJadhav: Ya It is not related to android, but i want try DNS configuration. Could you please help me. How can I configure DNS Server on `example.local`. Please share me any link/procedure that can help me. My example.local system is linux base system who has lots of capability to run DNS server. please help me?

Comment: You are confusing target host with DNS server. You already have a DNS server that you use in your dig command at 224.0.0.251. You need your device to know about it. I do not know how the network is configured on device, but the standard way to inform a network entity of a DNS server during network configuration would be to include it's (ip) address in DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

We can run ping command as below

ping `hostname -f`

and from the output in bracket we can see the IP address of the machine

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solve this issue from this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/37652284/5015103