# How to find IpAddress of system(server) in local network?

Tags: java, android, linux, networking, debian

I want to find IP address of my local server (system) which is run on debian-os in local network.  I am able to find all IP Addresses in local network, But that is so time consuming method. I want to find particular IP of my debian-sytem who has server running on it. This Debian-system connected to my local network through dynamic IP. I want to connect that server through device. But before connecting to server I have to find particular IP address of system in local network. How I can find IP address of particular server without getting all IP address in network?

Comment: That is what DNS is for.

Comment: @RonMaupin: If I install DNS on my `debian-system` then how can device get `IP` address of `debian-sytem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to setup a DNS-Server (either on the debian system itself, or on any other system, you might already have one too). Add a host entry (A-Record) for your debian system and provide the correct IP to the server.
On your clients you will have to configure the DNS-Server too. They may then refer to the debian system by DNS-Name.

Alternatively, if you are writing the client software too, you may use [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) to provide a "serverless" way of discovery, mDNS allows you to look for servers responding to a "DNS-Name" that you search for without an actual DNS-Server, this technique is often used by networked printers and multimedia devices. Chromecast uses a variation of mDNS too, to discover if a Chromecast device is present on the local network.

Comment: how can i achieve same thing without assigning static IP to both my server and client? because when I am configuring DNS server for my android-device it gives static IP. I do not want to do this.

Comment: Have a look at mDNS, it's the best solution available.

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699734/network-service-discovery-is-not-discover-service-type) link. I have an issue with `mDNS`.