# Network Service Discovery is not discover service type

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, tcp, mdns

I want to find server in my local network through android device. I am able to find it by using `NSDManager` service with service type of server(e.g `_workstation._tcp` is service type).


In my local network I have a 
wifi router and a wifi repeater, 
both have different **SSID** but same **password**. Wifi repeater is connected to router. Wifi repeater have same IP range as of router.
For example `192.168.0.1` is gateway of my router. IP of server is `192.168.0.100`. IP assign to wifi repeater is `192.168.0.101` and device connected to wifi repeater is `192.168.0.102`. 


When android device is connected to router, `NDSManager` service which run on application discovered service type of server and gives information about server. Following is output :

```
Example [xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]
```

Where Example is local hostname of server and [xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx] is mac address of server.

But When device is connected to wifi repeater and I want to find same server then it is not discovered by `NSDManager` service. It shows nothing. 

Why this happened? is NSDManger right method/functionality to find server in local network? if not then How can I find server in local network?

Comment: Is this what you are looking - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464207/android-find-a-server-in-the-network ?

Comment: Check if your devices broadcasts are visible on the server (run tcpdump/Wireshark)

Comment: @user755499 : thanks, my problem is solved

Comment: @sam - how is it solved, can you share the details please ? From the shared link of SO ?

Comment: @user755499 - write `UDP` socket on server which port has been continuously open. and then I implemented same code with some changes of link that you shared in my application. When application need server ip then  application open  port of `UDP` socket also send broadcast address over `UDP`. but here you have to maintain same port number on application and server.