# Where check/set timeout when java.net.UnknownHostException is thrown?

Tags: java, tomcat, httpurlconnection

Where check/set timeout when java.net.UnknownHostException is thrown?

Occasionally my code tries to connect to a non-existing location and throws java.net.UnknownHostException what is acceptable case in my app.

The problem I have is that it takes roughly about 20sec before the exception is thrown and it slows down the whole application.

The webserver version is Tomcat 7.0.37. I have tried change timeout settings (to 2sec) in the server.xml for following connectors:

```
Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="2000"
Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="2000" redirectPort="8443"
```

As I use HttpURLConnection I would expect the connection timeout setting for port 8080 to take effect, but it does not seem to be true.

I also tried to set the timeout within the code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);  
Reader reader= new InputStreamReader((InputStream) connection.getContent());
```

But this did not work neither, any ideas? Am I missing something?

ta

Comment: are you generally working on a slow internet connection? If so, did you try increasing the timeout? Try testing it on a high speed connection. If the problem still persists, then there is some issue in your logic which might be spawning too many threads.

Comment: You have a misconfigured DNS. Solve that.

Comment: @user927258 How increasing the timeout would help me to decrease the time spent on waiting for the java.net.UnknownHostException to be thrown?

Comment: @EJP that would be up to network administrator and not in my powers, i got to address it in my app, ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is probably being spent looking up the host in DNS, which in your case seems to be timing out when trying to look up a host that can't be found. This happens if the DNS server you connect to forwards the request to another DNS server, and doesn't get a reply in a reasonable amount of time, perhaps because it's not well configured.

You can solve this problem in the operating system level by making the DNS lookup timeout earlier; for example in Linux you could add `options timeout:2` to `/etc/resolv.conf` to make DNS lookups timeout in 2 seconds instead of the default. On Windows you have to [edit a registry setting](https://serverfault.com/questions/431207/adjust-windows-dns-timeout-similar-to-the-linux-resolv-conf).

Alternatively you can solve this in your program by [using a thread for the name resolution](http://thushw.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/resolving-domain-names-quickly-with.html). If the thread doesn't return in a timeout you specify you assume that name resolution will throw an `UnknownHostException`.

A third option is using a different, better behaved DNS server, like the ones maintained by Google at 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, It seems to me it indeed is problem with DNS. Summing up default times DNSQueryTimeouts (given in post "edit a registry setting" ) gives 17 seconds which would explain why I am waiting for about that time for the action if unavailable host called.

Comment: Yet another option is using a different DNS servers if you can. 8.8.8.8 (maintained by Google) is pretty fast and won't make you  wait to tell you if they can't resolve a name. Come to think of it, I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is a DNS resolution problem not a Java one, I guess that your program is blocked during the DNS query. Try to perform an nslookup on an unknown host inside a shell to see if you reproduce the problem. If you are, ask your system administrator to look at the DNS server logs and configuration if there's something wrong.

If the hosts are frequently the same, look at this post to configure the negative ttl to cache the Unknown host responses from the DNS : 
[any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl)