# Tomcat caches old dns entry of Single Sign On system‏

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, dns, single-sign-on

I have Tomcat 6.0.14 (installed in RedHat Linux 5.5 and with Java 6 update 13) integrated with a SSO (Single Sign On) system.

When SSO fail overs to a different data center (and SSO's IP address changes) the Tomcat continues to stick to the old DNS entry of the SSO system.

I then have to restart the Tomcat container so that it picks the new DNS of the SSO system. I have to restart the Tomcat every time SSO system fails over to different data center.

Is there a way to configure Tomcat to refresh DNS with out restarting when SSO fails over?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't Tomcat specific, but rather specific to the virtual machine. In particular, see the documentation for [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256766/274466) provides the solution, but I'll give some options for completeness:

There seem to be three options:

1. Edit the `java.security` file found in `$JRE_HOME/lib/security` and change the `networkaddress.cache.ttl` to something sensible instead of -1 (the default more or less).
2. Modify the command that launches Tomcat to change the setting, i.e. at the parameter `-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=xxx` where `xxx` is some sensible value.
3. Change it within your app by running: `java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "xxx");`

Comment: That sounds right to me, and here is a SO post about Java DNS caching and how to set TTL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl