# Yahoo POP3 and IMAP refuse connection sometimes

Tags: spring-boot, centos, jakarta-mail, imap, yahoo

I have a web app deployed on CentOS7 server.

My web app sends mail via (SMTP) and reads mail via(POP3/IMAP)from YAHOO server.
All my configuration are correct and am making request via SSL.

I am facing some unusual behavior on server, sometimes it gets connected sometimes it does not .Most of the time this issue is fixed when i redeploy my app.

[Note : Firewall is turned off on server ]

My app is build on Spring Boot.

Please Help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually implement round robin DNS.  There are many servers in the IMAP and POP3 pools, and if one doesn't work, you should try the next:

For my location, I get 8 servers in the IMAP pool, with distinct IPs.

```
> nslookup imap.mail.yahoo.com
Non-authoritative answer:
imap.mail.yahoo.com     canonical name = imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net.
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 67.195.125.200
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 67.195.125.129
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 66.218.75.98
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 67.195.236.147
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 66.218.74.148
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 98.138.74.46
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 66.218.75.97
Name:   imap.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net
Address: 98.138.74.42
```

I don't know if Javamail rotates through servers automatically.

Comment: But it never fails when i request from my local windows machine.

Comment: JavaMail just uses the JDK to make the connection.  The [JDK does cache host names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl), so that may be part of the problem.  Still, you would need to retry the connection in the case of failure.