# Okhttp dns cache invalidation

Tags: dns, okhttp

I use okhttp for communicating between backend microservices. The service discovery is implemented on top of consul dns.
As a result some instances/pods, associated to a given IP can be removed at any time.
The problem is that okhttp caches the resolved ip address and when some associated instance becomes unavailable we see spikes of java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

I would like to understand, how does the dns cache is invalidated?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/how-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout

Comment: +1 to the link above. OkHttp isn't caching resolved ip address.  But could be retaining a new deead connection from when it was first successfully used.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that we already disable dns cache at jvm level using networkaddress.cache.ttl

Comment: @nicolattu did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @tallkid24 yes, I did a network interceptor with a try catch, and when there is timeout exception i close the socket of the current connection, next request does dns lookup again.